# What's the best way to copy a directory from a remote VM onto your local PC

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, azure

Just a quick,  probably silly question, but I have an Ubuntu virtual machine running on Microsoft Azure. A package that I installed has generated some files onto the virtual machine, and I need to access those files. I've tried to connect via SFTP, but my credentials won't work when trying to download the files (I have permissions to know it exists, but not to view it).
What would be the best way to transfer such files onto my PC? Thanks! (I connect to the VM using SSH)

Comment: If you can't copy them with SFTP, then the ID you log in with isn't allowed to read the files, and other methods will suffer the same problem if you use them with the same id. So you have to solve this problem first (possibly by adding your id to the relevant group). Once you have done this, all methods should work (but I would prefer `rsync` if you copy big files).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `/path/to/your/files` when logged in with `ssh user@host` you can also download them with `rsync "user@host:/path/to/your/files" ./` or `scp "user@host:/path/to/your/files" ./` to your current directory.